# Could one triple the moon’s mass without it colliding with earth if it was done slowly enough?

Tags: space, gravity, moons, earth, terraforming

In my story, Earth is dead, and for religious reasons, humanity decides it needs to live on the Moon now. However, they want to triple the mass of the Moon to increase gravity to 5m/s or so. Assuming they have a method to transfer double the Moon’s original mass from Earth to the Moon through terraforming over a long period, is there a way they can do this while avoiding the Moon eventually degrading and slamming into Earth? Could it be done by simply doing it relatively slowly (I.e. over thousands of years)?

Comment: Some maths for you: tripling the mass, will increase the gravity from 1.625 to 2.342 only. To get to 5, you need to increase the mass to about 2.5 times *that of Mars*. i.e. 22 times the mass of the Moon. Unless you have some means to compress 3 times the mass of the moon into one moon size sphere without problems, in which case your tech is **so** far-out that mere planetary orbital dynamics is of no concern whatsoever to you.

Comment: @PcMan - just use heavier elements. Maybe having thorium and tungsten in excess is not that bad for Moon's climate - lotsa incandescent light bulbs to be made on the cheap, more energy trapped as heat.

Comment: @PoMan Huh. I may have messed up my math, but I thought mass and gravitational force were directly proportional if radius is constant (which I was assuming in this case, though obviously actually doing so requires some hand waving). This leads to a follow up question (that I could put as another question if preferred): if you didn’t change the mass of the moon at all, but instead just compressed it into a smaller shape, you could still increase the gravity without altering the mass, right? Is this any more reasonable of a possibility?

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to build giant centrifuges in the moon colonies to similate gravity?

Comment: @MarkPrice if you wanted radius to remain constant, you should have said so in your question! Magically increasing the density of the moon would have the effect you wanted, but make no mistake... compressing the moon does imply magic.

Answer (score 2):

Moon and Earth orbit their center of mass, which in the present configuration of masses is located about 2000 km away from the center of Earth.

Rearranging the masses as you propose the center of mass would move at about 6000 km away from the center of Earth, very close to its surface. This shift of 4000 km would be a mere 1% of the distance between the two bodies, and the key point for not affecting the orbit is that you will need to match the Moon orbital velocity when depositing the new material. So, instead of slamming rocks one after the other and letting the Moon share its momentum with the arriving load, you would need to gently land those rocks with a negligible velocity with respect to the Moon, so that no lunar momentum has to be lost.

Comment: You _will_ need to give the Moon some momentum, because the Sun is already there. Moon's orbit around the Sun is convex, which means Sun's influence on the Moon is higher than Earth's influence (carry on a computation on the two forces, not that hard) - the Moon and Earth are two bodies that just happen to orbit the Sun together. Adjusting the Moon mass without adding to its orbital velocity will increase the Sun's attraction to it, making it to fall in a "lower" orbit than it is now (gain speed and getting a shorter solar year). True, it will drag a bit the Earth down as well, but …

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the answer. It was obvious to me that directly adding to the moon’s velocity wasn’t really possible but I didn’t think you could control it through the added mass. This may lead to some experimentation in KSP :)

Answer (score 0):

The moon is actually moving away from the Earth, not getting closer. And the mass of the moon is only 1.2% that of Earth, so a gradual change isn't that bad. Tides, weather and things would change but since they won't be living on it who cares. They would adjust rotation and speed rather than crash into each other.

The moon used to be much closer but the Earths days were much shorter. So they affect each other like that. In terms of three times the mass you have huge problems.

Where are you getting the mass from and how are you transporting it to the moon? Are you lightening the Earth by 2 times the mass of the moon? If it's from the Earth then it's a pretty expensive payload.

Comment: "If it's from the Earth" I'd place an order for star dust from the nearest nebula suppliers and sprinkle it gently on the Moon.

Comment: @AdrianColomitchi but where does the sprinkler come from?

Comment: Delivered by the supplier. Special order. May take a geological era or two, but the Moon is already a dead body, so about that time the Milky Way collides with the Magellanic cloud on a trajectory arranged for the Moon to pass through that nebula? That time  shouldn't matter that much.

Comment: I just thought about this again and this is a good point. I assumed over 2500 years or so, a few advanced spacecraft could lug 1.5e23 kg of material to the moon, but that would mean 6e19 kg per year. That’s a lot of fuel lol.